# How can I make all this code work under backgroundworker

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Right now I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    var dialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string sWybranyPlik;
    if (dialogResult  == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      sWybranyPlik = openFileDialog1.FileName;

      try
      {


        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sWybranyPlik + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"); 

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter OleDBAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Tabelle1$]", ExcelConnection);

        DtSet.Clear();


        //wypełnianie datagridview
        OleDBAdapter.Fill(DtSet.Tables[0]);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];


        //kasowanie starych danych w bazie danych
        string deletesql = @"DELETE FROM TabelaProdukty";
        System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand comDelete = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand(deletesql, sqlconnection);
        sqlconnection.Open();
        comDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconnection.Close();


        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); 
        progressform.ShowDialog();



        ExcelConnection.Close();
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
    }
}
```

And in _DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

  //wprowadzanie nowych danych z datagridview do bazy danych
  string strQuery = @"INSERT INTO TabelaProdukty VALUES (@VD, @ItemCode, @Item, @Qty, @Ppcur, @StandardPrice, @CeMarked, @Description, @Description2, @Edma)";
  sqlconnection.Open();
  using (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand(strQuery, sqlconnection))
  {
    comm.Parameters.Add("@VD", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Ppcur", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@StandardPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@CeMarked", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Description2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Edma", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

      comm.Parameters["@VD"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["VD"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@ItemCode"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ItemCode"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Item"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Qty"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QUANTITY"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Ppcur"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PPCUR"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@StandardPrice"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STANDARD_SELL_PRICE"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@CeMarked"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CE-MARKED"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Description"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Description2"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ITEM_DESCRIPTION2"].Value.ToString().Trim();
      comm.Parameters["@Edma"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EDMA"].Value.ToString().Trim();


      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

      if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
      {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
      }

    }
    sqlconnection.Close();


  }
}
```

As you can see this code lets me pick a excel file with OpenFileDialog,  clears DataSet, fills a dataset and datagridview with data, clears SQL table nad then it opens a form with a progress bar showing a long process of copying a data from datagridview to sql databse (around 150000 rows in 12 columns.
At this point it works ok. The problem I have is that everything before opening progressform takes time too, so I would like to put it all under backgroundworker and in progressform show the status reports like "Old data is deleted" or table "Loading new data", and then run progressbar for the dgv->sql part. Unfortunately by putting this code under _DoWork I get different errors depending on how much code do I copy there (all of button1_Click or only "try" part).

Do you have any ideas how it should look?

Best regards,

EDIT:

Additional methods:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

  progressform.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Operacja przerwana! Cennik nie został wprowadzony w całości", "Uwaga!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


  }
  else
  {

    progressform.label1.Text = "Zakończono pomyślnie! :)";
    progressform.button1.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `reportProgress` event of backgroundworker.

Save the filename from `openfiledialog` in a string at instance level, i.e. outside the methods. Now shift the code for populating `dataset` completely in the `backgroundworker.dowork` eventhandler. After populating `dataset` call `backgroundworker.ReportProgress`. This will trigger `backgroundworker.ProgressChanged` event. Populate your datagridview within this method since this method will be invoked on the thread where the backgroundworker was instantiated. Now send the rest of your ADO connection codes in the `dowork` method. this should be enough.

```
**EDIT**

class YourClass
    {
        string filePath;
        DataSet dataset;
        private static void Do_Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //populate dataset
            //call worker.ReportProgress to trigger worker.ProgressChanged 
            //rest of time consuming ADO.Net Codes and other codes you wrote in your DoWork method
        }

        private static void Progress_Changed(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this method is invoked in the thread where background worker is instantiated.
            //do all UI stuff here like populating datagridview from dataset
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get this (which is not easy, because I'm just stariting with c#). Anyway, yousay that I should put the code for populating dataset under reportprogress. This event is already called during loading into sql to make progressbar work. How should I make it to know if reportchanged event should do the dataset or sql part? some if method? Or maybe I did not understand you... (probably this ;) )

Comment: Have you included the progresschanged method?

Comment: Thanks, it is clearer what you have in mind, but still cannot get it work. I call reportprogress with argument 0, so in progresschanged i make if (... == 0) { and here datagridview populated with datase} but I get an defalt dgv erro that index 0 have no value

Comment: Ok. I googled a bit more. I learned that I have to make every UI change outside of _dowork. So I tried to put dataset.clear and excel file load to progress_changed event. But it does not work as I hoped. Problems are sometimes with loop not working (dgv->sql loop) and with progressbar not working properly (stopping at half or not moving at all). Anyway +1 for  making me realize how this should work.